# ".Add" on Dictionary with a list as value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I've been struggling to Google this question as I can't get the wording quite right (hence the title).

The gist is why do one of the below work, is there a shorthand for **test3**:

```
  var test1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  test1["Derp"] = 10; // Success

  var test2 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
  test2["Derp"].Add(10); // Fail

  var test3 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
  test3["Derp"] = new List<int>();
  test3["Derp"].Add(10); // Success
```

A scenario I'm coming across often is similar to the below (this is a very basic example):

```
  var names = new List<string>() { "Jim", "Fred", "Fred", "Dave", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim" };

  var nameCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

  foreach(var name in names)
  {
    if (!nameCounts.ContainsKey(name))
      nameCounts.Add(name, 0);

    nameCounts[name]++;
  }
```

In other words - is there a way to skip the "ContainsKey" check, and go straight to adding to my list (and key automatically)?

Edit: to be clear, I hadn't used the below as in my real-life situation, it isn't quite as simple (unfortunately!)

```
var nameCounts = names.GroupBy(x => x)
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Comment: Use `TryGetValue` rather than `ContainsKey`. The general pattern I would recommend is https://dotnetfiddle.net/jPGk8E . Or consider `MultiValueDictionary` - https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1306 .

Comment: As the answers say, the way to do this is to write an extension method that has the semantics you want. But for your specific scenario, there is a better way to do that. You can just write the one-liner `var nameCounts = names.GroupBy(x=>x).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Count());`

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert. I knew somebody would throw the GroupBy at me. Unfortunately that wouldn't work in my real-life scenario as the code is a little more complicated than I could explain. Thank you, anyway! :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you have a "more complicated" scenario, my advice is to create a type that has the exact semantics you want. I do this all the time; in a recent project I needed to make a half a dozen different kinds of dictionaries, each with a slightly different semantics -- some were counting occurrences, some were maps from keys to lists, some were many-many relations, and so on -- so I made a wrapper type around the dictionary type for each, and gave each type *exactly* the signature for `Add`, and `Get` and so on, that I needed. It made the resulting code easy to write and read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl calls this auto-vivification, and I use some extensions to `Dictionary` to implement various forms, you would need the one that uses a lambda to generate the initial values:

```
//***
// Enhanced Dictionary that auto-creates missing values with seed lambda
// ala auto-vivification in Perl
//***
public class SeedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    Func<TValue> seedFn;
    public SeedDictionary(Func<TValue> pSeedFn) : base() {
        seedFn = pSeedFn;
    }
    public SeedDictionary(Func<TValue> pSeedFn, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> d) : base() {
        seedFn = pSeedFn;
        foreach (var kvp in d)
            Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out var val))
                base[key] = (val = seedFn());
            return val;
        }
        set => base[key] = value;
    }
}
```

So then you could do test2 like so:

```
var test2 = new SeedDictionary<string, List<int>>(() => new List<int>());
test2["Derp"].Add(10); // works
```

For your name counts example, you could use the version that auto-creates the default value for the value type:

```
//***
// Enhanced Dictionary that auto-creates missing values as default
// ala auto-vivification in Perl
//***
public class AutoDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    public AutoDictionary() : base() { }
    public AutoDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> d) : base() {
        foreach (var kvp in d)
            Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out var val))
                base[key] = val;
            return val;
        }
        set => base[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Woazers - I see. I was hoping for something in-built, but I definitely want to try this as it's using a lot of techniques I don't get chance to use in my day-to-day. I'll also try and remember the term "autovivification" for when I want to explain why I'm going ott with my Dictionaries. Thank you :)

Comment: @Oyyou - A warning should be made on this implementation - it uses `new` to shadow the `this` indexer and that means that anything that casts this back to `Dictionary<K, V>` will use the standard implementation of the `this` indexer. It would be better to do a full implementation of `IDictionary<K,V>` instead.

Comment: @Enigmativity Wouldn't an implementation of `IReadOnlyDictionary<K,V>` and `IDictionary` also be needed? I'm not sure that behaving as a regular `Dictionary` in contexts that expect one is a bad thing...

Comment: @NetMage - The only requirements of `IDictionary<K, V>` are `ICollection<KeyValuePair<K, V>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>, IEnumerable`. I don't think an object behaving differently in different contexts is a good thing.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ah - you originally said "casts this back to `Dictionary<K,V>` and not `IDictionary<K,V>`... So, you don't think `Dictionary<>` should implement `IReadOnlyDictionary` or `ExpandoObject` implement `IDictionary`?

Comment: @NetMage - No, I don't.

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can do this (among many), is a little extension method (cutesy of Jon Skeet [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/02/05/a-simple-extension-method-but-a-beautiful-one/))

```
public static TValue GetOrCreate<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,TKey key) where TValue : new() 
{
    TValue ret;
    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ret))
    {
        ret = new TValue();
        dictionary[key] = ret;
    }
    return ret; 
 }
```

**Usage**

```
strong textvar test2 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
var myNewList = test2.GetOrCreate("Derp");
myNewList.Add(10); 

// or

var test2 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
test2.GetOrCreate("Derp").Add(10); // winning!
```

---

<sub>***Note*** : In all my early morning pep, i actually didn't look at this question, [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) is on the money in the comments, this can be simply done via a [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) and a projection to a dictionary with [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8) without all the extra fluff of extension methods and classes</sub>

Cutesy of [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)

```
// Count occurrences of names in a list 
var nameCounts = names.GroupBy(x => x)
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.GroupBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)

> Groups the elements of a sequence.

[Enumerable.ToDictionary Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I wouldn't stress about it; you answered the question that was asked, with a reasonable answer.

Comment: Now I wonder if a `GetOrDefault` to go with `GetOrCreate` would be better than my auto-vivifying wrappers...

Comment: @NetMage if you're worried, I'm worried

Comment: @Oyyou LOL. It's just a matter of style. I also considered an `AutoRef` class that creates a reference type automatically with an implicit conversion operator, but it won't work in most places (until Extension Everywhere is implemented perhaps).

Comment: @NetMage seems like a worthy addition to your class. I have secretly stashed yours away in a base lib of mine already ;) upvote

Comment: @TheGeneral TY. I have it in My Extensions for LINQPad.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key)
        where TValue : new()
        => dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue val) ? val : dict[key] = new TValue();
```

Edit: Another way is:

```
TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key)
        where TValue : new()
        => dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[key] : dict[key] = new TValue();
```

I'm not sure if this is as performant, but it works on older C# versions, where my first example doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative with [C# 7 out variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7) :

```
foreach(var name in names)
{
    nameCounts[name] = nameCounts.TryGetValue(name, out var count) ? count + 1 : 1;
}
```